# Double integral $\iint_D \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}} dxdy$ where $D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le 1,x \ge0\}$

Tags: integration

Compute

$\iint_D \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}} dxdy$

where $D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le 1,x\ge0\}$

The answer is $\frac{(2−\sqrt{2})\pi}{6}$.

How can I set variables to calculate this.

I tried it with $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ but it didn't work well.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work well? Can you show your work?

Comment: the change to polar coordinates works very well, as it separates the double integral in the product of two distinct integrals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\iint_D \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}} \,dx \,dy
&= \int_0^1 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{r^3 \cos^2(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+r^2}} \,d \theta \,dr \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{r^3}{\sqrt{1+r^2}} \,dr \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(2 \theta) + 1}{2} \,d \theta
\end{align}

Now, we have

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(2 \theta) + 1}{2} \,d \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{r^3}{\sqrt{1+r^2}} \,dr &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u}} \,du  
&(u= r^2) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_1^2 \frac{s-1}{\sqrt{s}} \,ds &(s = 1+u) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_1^2 s^{\frac{1}{2}} - s^{-\frac{1}{2}} \,ds \\
&= \frac{2}{3} (2 - \sqrt{2})
\end{align}

giving a final answer of $\frac{\pi (2 - \sqrt{2})}{3}$. There might be some mistake which I'm not aware of which causes the answer not to be the one you claimed.